# Saving image with php error

Tags: php, gd

i am creating a image and attempting to save the file. The image creates fine but i am struggling to save the image.

the error i receive when i simple try to save the image using imagepng() is 'The image “https://examplemydomain.com/email/tweet.image.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.' i have the domain set to chmod 777.

I have tried creating another file to call the image as well but this does not work either
example: tweet.image.save.php

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/email/tweet.image.php'; // your url here
$data = file_get_conents($url);
file_put_conents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/email/tweet.png', $data);
?>
```

example of image creation: tweet.image.php

```
<?php

//ini_set('display_errors',1); 
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/twitter.php');

$color = RgbfromHex('FFFFFF');

$text = "This is an example tweet for noise agency ltd. I hope it shows up in less than 140 characters and does not overrun on to new lines. looks ok";

$text_length = 75;
$sig = wordwrap($text, $text_length, "<br />", true);

$font = '../fonts/arial.ttf';

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(402, 33);

$bg_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 88,158,214);

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 402, 33, $bg_color);

$text = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $sig);

$counttext = strlen($sig);

if ($counttext > 75) {
    $startpos = 12;
} else {
    $startpos = 20;
}
imagettftext($im, 9.1, 0, 0, $startpos, $font_color, $font, $text);

$filename = "tweet"; 
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/email/".$filename.".png";

chmod($directory,0755);
imagepng($im, $directory, 0, NULL);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);

imagedestroy($im);

function RgbfromHex($hexValue) {
    if(strlen(trim($hexValue))==6) {
        return array(
                     hexdec(substr($hexValue,0,2)), // R
                     hexdec(substr($hexValue,2,2)), // G
                     hexdec(substr($hexValue,4,2))  // B
                    );
    }
    else return array(0, 0, 0);
}

?>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks

Comment: You can use file_put_contents with the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Document root is relative to the current url based position. You need to supply the full system uri to the save path. For example: file_put_contents( '/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/email/tweet.png', $content );

Comment: @OleHaugset Thank you for your help i have changed this to the full path but still no luck. also tried the full path in imagepng($im, $directory, 0, NULL); as well :(

Comment: You are not getting that error when _saving_ the image; the error is about _displaying_ the image. Have you verified that a valid image is really generated? What does it say in the error log? What is output to the browser when you remove `header('Content-type: image/png');`?

Comment: file_get_conents isnt a valid function, is file_get_contents